# Running two instances of the same Java application

Tags: java, instance

I want to start two instances of the same Java project. I am able to start two instances by clicking on the "Run" button twice, but when I click "exit" for the first instance, it closes both. I want each instant to work separately. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: try to use different ports for and run project

Comment: it is not a web application. just a standlone

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse 2020-12

Answer (score 1):

1. In Eclipse switch to **Debug View**
2. Switch to the **Debug** tab (it should be where your package explorer and project explorer tabs are)
3. Launch multiple instances of the application you need to run
4. **Verify in the Debug tab there are actually multiple instances running**
5. Click the red **Stop** button

Only one instance should stop. Otherwise something is up with your Eclipse, as far as I am aware "Stop All" is not a function that is available by default. This makes me think you do not actually have multiple instances running at the moment you press **Stop**. Maybe one starts and shuts down immediately, because the other is already running and shared resources are used (which is typical e.g. of servers).

In any case, you need to verify that multiple instances actually are running when you try to stop one. Not whether you started two instances, but whether both are alive when the attempt to stop one is made.

If you actually do have two active instances you can:

1. Repeat steps 1.-4. in the list above
2. Select the instance you want to stop in the **Debug View**
3. Then press the **Stop** button

The correct Eclipse behavior is to then stop the selected runtime.